# file_get_contents on a url that redirects

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `file_get_contents()` on an image url which redirects to another image url. This results in a PHP error `file_get_contents(www.modernpads.info/p/2161621.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

1. Is there a way to `get` that image file even though the initial url redirects to another url?
2. If the above cannot be done, how can I not return the PHP error and simply ignore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirect isn't your problem; it looks like the URL is missing an `http` scheme. Without the scheme, PHP thinks it's a file.